# How can I set visibility of certain columns to only display based on who the report is sent to

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report built in SSRS to show the current projects that our teams are working on, each one dedicated towards a business group (Marketing, Retail etc). *Is it possible to have this one report be sent out to each business group but only showing its own respective business group*? So for marketing, have retail projects invisible etc. I have looked into adding parameters and somehow incorporating them into the Subscriptions but I have yet to figure it out, excuse my lack of knowledge on the subject and sorry if this thing has been asked before! Thank you!                                                                                                    [image: Manage Subscriptions Options]

Comment: Is there a field in your dataset that lets you determine what group it's for? Then if you make it a parameter, set up the subscription for each group to use just that one parameter choice for their data. Would need to see what the data is like to say more.  Although data driven subscriptions might work, a normal subscription would work as well

Comment: There is a field for Business Group, which contains all the information regarding each each group, I just want to filter the report to only show the business group it is sending to, so for marketing for example, it would have a filter to only show when business group = marketing. I've tried setting up a parameter, which allows me to select a value from the business group field, but doesn't seem to do anything or give me options to set it to do something. Again forgive my cluelessness on the subject, it can never be overestimated!

Comment: The parameter would need to filter the dataset to do anything.  It's a view or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [Data Driven Subscriptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169673.aspx) are perfect for.

In your report, create parameters that you can reference either in your report to show or hide different elements (using the `Hidden` property) or in your query to limit the data that is returned.

Then, set up a query that details who you need to send the report to and the various values that you would need to run the report against for their particular requirements.  This query is then used by the data driven subscription to run the report, with the specified parameters and send it to the given email address.

That is it.

Think of it as giving a list to a colleague and saying "For each email address in this list, run the report with the parameter values next to the email and then send the report that is produced to the email address." but instead of a colleague doing the actual running and sending, it is SSRS.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Is it really necessary to use the data driven subscriptions and setting up a new database? I don't mind if I've to set up multiple subscriptions, I just want to apply a one filter depending on who I'm sending it to. The logic seems simple,    IF Suscription = User X

Comment: IF Subscription set to User X then Filter set to A, IF User Y then Filter set to B etc etc.

Comment: @FrankNewToThis  I don't understand why you would need a new database?  Have a look through the documentation I linked and try to create a simple one.  It is much easier than your probably think!

Comment: Apologies I was just going by the link you provided above, where in Lesson 1 it states you need to create a Database. I have just added a Parameter but it gives me no options besides setting what values are in the parameter? Not what it will do when it is selected. Could you possibly elaborate on what you mean / do when you say set up a query - I have not done so before within ssrs (or outside of it much either!). Again, apologies for my noobness.. Thank you!

Comment: @FrankNewToThis  Lesson 1 is so you have some data to use and Lesson 2 is so you have a report to subscribe to.  As the name suggests, Lesson 3 is where you "Define a Data-Driven Subscription."  To send the report to different people based on parameter usage, you need to create a query that returns a row for each combination of email address and parameters to run the report that you need generated.  You then set it to run the report with the parameters in the row and send it to the email in that same row.  You will get one report generated and sent per row returned.

Comment: Thank you for baring with me so far, it must be painful ha. When I go straight to lesson 3 I am not presented with the options it is telling me to do. For example it tells me to "Type Sales Order delivery in description". In my version I don't have a description field. It then says click Data-driven subscription. I don't have that field either. Or alot of the fields it continues to describe. The picture below is what I have while managing subscriptions. Also, you mention I need to create a query. i

Comment: I have never done so before, are you referring to creating a SQL query? How would I do that?

Comment: @FrankNewToThis  In your screenshot you are creating a regular subscription, not a data-driven one.  In the Report Manager, find the report you want to subscribe to and click `Manage`, then `Subscriptions` and then at the top of the screen click on `New Data Driven Subscription`.

Comment: I must be on a different version. There is no 'Manage' option, only 'Manage Subscriptions', which brings me to the page I linked above. I can't seem to find any mention of "New Data Driven Subscription"